# Basics: Retrieve Node attribute definition boxes and noodles

Tags: node-editor, shaders, navigation

On save and re-open, objects display the node attributes defined previously, but in Shader Editor, how do you display the definition dialogs and noodles? (The screen is black, even when an object is displayed) node attributes are retained, so how do I retrieve the Node input/out definition boxes and the noodles connecting them?
[image]

I want:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not just off screen? Go to ```View > Frame All``` or press ```Home``` on the keyboard. This will bring everything back on screen if it was in fact off screen.

Comment: Thanks for that. Home works great. After taking the splinters out of my forehead, I also found Select > Find Node > Principle BSDF